# Disable the hyperlinks in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable links in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098797/disable-links-in-uiwebview)

How can i disable the hyperlinks in a `UIWebView` and make it look like a normal text?

Answer (score 8):

Set this property of UIWebview

```
yourWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

First set delegate to `UIWebView` when you want to use this method...

```
[self.webview setDelegate:sethere];
```

after that you can use the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` delegate method of `UIWebView` in which you add this type of logic to disable hyperlinks like bellow...

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
 {

            NSURL *loadURL = [[request URL]retain];
            //change next line to whatever condition you need, e.g.
            //[[loadURL relativeString]  ....] contains a certain substring 
            //or starts with certain letter or ...
            if([[loadURL scheme] isEqualToString: @"file"])
            {
               [loadURL release]; 
            return TRUE;
            }
            [loadURL release];
            return FALSE;
  }
```

Also see the Reference from this [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) link

i hope this help you....

Comment: @Daij-Djan hey dude see the answer here i put condition with url scheme , if here condition tru then its return true otherwise return false dude.. :)

Comment: this line return true when content store the file which just allowed http:// or https:// so another hyperlinks not true here dude... for more info read about scheme of NSURL and also for UIWebView dude...

Comment: yes right here url or loadurl both works here dude.. just refer something and just test it and debug it dude.. :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan ok dude see the another answer about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783074/disable-hyperlinks-in-uiwebview this is same like my code...

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the content inside the `UIWebView` but you can disable the `UIWebView` responding to the links inside it by giving the `UIWebView` a delegate and implement the following in your code:

`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method to `return NO;`